# Inherited Properties not visible in Debugger - Blazor

Tags: c#, inheritance, blazor, visual-studio-debugging

Im working on a Blazor app and I implemented some classes that have inheritance. When I create a Derived Class object it works fine and I can access and set all the values that it inherited from the Base Class, but when I hit a breakpoint and use the debugger to inspect the object, it only shows the properties that are in the derived class.

Whats happening?

Classes:

```
public class Event {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Title { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

public class Shift :Event{
  //[Required]
  public ShiftRepeat Repeat { get; set; }
  //[Required]
  public List<Break> Breaks { get; set; }
  public Shift ShallowCopy() {
    return (Shift)this.MemberwiseClone();
  }
}
```

Element Debugger is inspecting

```
      var n = new Shift() {
        Id = 1,
        Title = "Shift 1",
        Start = new DateTime(2021, 1, 18, 8, 0, 0),
        End = new DateTime(2021, 1, 18, 16, 0, 0),
        Repeat = ShiftRepeat.Daily,
        Breaks = new List<Break>() {
          new Break() {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Lunch",
            Start = new DateTime(2021, 1, 18, 12, 0, 0),
            End = new DateTime(2021, 1, 18, 12, 30, 0)
          }
        }
      };
```

[Debugger inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETc86.png)
[One Drive File Download](https://mailuc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/personal/schindim_mail_uc_edu/Documents/newapptest.zip?csf=1&web=1&e=JKliua)

Comment: please include code ***as formatted text*** i your question - ***not*** as sceenshot.

Comment: I can't show the debugger inspect window as formatted text. It has to be a screenshot to show what I'm seeing.

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to make sure you understood that. You're right, I was cutting corners. I apologize for being defensive.

Comment: don't worry, you improved your question, and all is okay :)

Comment: Could you provide more information about the app? What .NET version are you using? Which hosting model is in place? Server or WASM?

Comment: its a local web app, not a server. where do i check the .net version, though i think its 7

Answer (score 0):

**Actually**, I can see the inherited properties during debugging.

[image]

Maybe try the following suggestions:

**1)** disable any installed third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

**2)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**

**3)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder and then restart your project

**4)** run `devnev /safemode` under Developer Command prompt for VS to start a pure VS and then test your project under that instance.

**5)** or you could try to create a new blazor app and then test your code under that new proejct.

**6)** update your VS if there is a new release version or [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) under vs_installer

Comment: i tried all of these and none of them worked. any other ideas?

Comment: also in your picture you show that you can see all the inherited properties of the break class, but can you confirm the same is true for the shift class?

Comment: See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfQCY.png), the properties of shirt class are all listed there. Maybe you should try to reset vs environment to the default. Enter `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx`. Rename `16.0_xxxx` to `VS2019_Backup`(make a backup of your VS2019 environment). Then, restart VS2019 to test it.

Comment: Or you could share a reproducible sample of your issue with us to help us try the sample in our side.

Comment: How do i share the .zip file?

Comment: You can use onedrive with a shared file or  a public github repository. And add that link into your issue to involve  anyone else who could get that link obviously into your problem.